# Cursor returns unexpected results

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I have the following sql code and it is not behaving as expected.  It seems to return two different datasets(not sure if dataset it the right explanation) with a record each instead of one dataset with two records.

My sql is supposed to read a table with country and tracking number.  If I find the country I am querying for I return the tracking number(s) to a cursor.  In my example I have two tracking numbers in my cursor.  I then loop through the sql to acquire the information from several tables and put the results into one record for that tracking number(that part works).  The second time it does the same thing for the second tracking number except it appears to put the second record in it's own dataset.  I was expecting to have one result with two records yet it seems to be two separate results.  Can someone help explain and give possible guidance?

Here is my sql

```
DECLARE @cur_trk_link VARCHAR(50)
--Declare Cursor
DECLARE Student_Cursor CURSOR FOR 

--Select trk_link from cc_ptms for passed CC

SELECT trk_link FROM CC_PTMS WHERE cc = 'JA'


--opne cursor
OPEN Student_Cursor

--Fetch from Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Student_Cursor INTO @cur_trk_link

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN

    --execute main function to create records
    SELECT Top 1 t.trk_link

         ,(SELECT track + ' ' + country_na FROM TT_DTL AS td WHERE td.[trk_link]=LEFT (t.[trk_link], 20)) AS TrainingTrackCountry 

          ,t.scn
          ,t.given_nm AS FirstName
          ,t.surname_nm AS LastName
          ,t.cc AS CC
          ,t.sex AS Sex
          ,t.grade AS Grade
          ,t.dob AS StudentDob
          ,t.marital_st AS MaritalStatus
          ,t.pob_cntry AS BirthCountry
          ,t.pob_city AS BirthCity
          ,CASE t.UScitizenship_CD
              WHEN 'H' THEN 'Holds'
              WHEN 'DNH' THEN 'Does Not Hold'
              ELSE ''
              END AS StuCitizenStatus

          ,p.pass_nbr as Passport#
         ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + pass_nbr FROM VI AS v WHERE v.[trk_link]=t.[trk_link] FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1 ,'') AS Visa#
           ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + given_nm+' '+ surname_nm FROM PD AS p2 where p2.[trk_link]=t.[trk_link] FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1 ,'') AS DependentName
           ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + dep_rel FROM PD AS p2 WHERE p2.[trk_link]=t.[trk_link] FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1 ,'') AS DependentRelationship
           ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Convert(VARCHAR, birth_dt) FROM PD AS p2 where p2.[trk_link]=t.[trk_link] FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1 ,'') AS DependentDob
           ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CASE UScitizenship_CD   WHEN 'H' THEN 'Holds'
              WHEN 'DNH' THEN 'Does Not Hold'
              ELSE ''
              END FROM PD AS p2 WHERE p2.[trk_link]=t.[trk_link] FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1 ,'') AS DepCitizenStatus


    from TP t
    Left outer join P p
    on t.[trk_link] = p.[trk_link]
    Left outer join PD p2 on t.[trk_link] = p2.[trk_link]

    WHERE t.trk_link = @cur_trk_link

    FETCH NEXT FROM Student_Cursor INTO @cur_trk_link

    END

    CLOSE  Student_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE  Student_Cursor'
```

Can someone assist?  Thanks Penelope

[Sample of results]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you execute a select statement. Each time it executes, it will generate a resultset of 1 row. If your goal is to generate 1 resultset containing all of the rows that "match", you will need to temporarily store them in a table (permanent, temp, or variable).  But from what you posted, you don't need a cursor at all. Replace the where clause with something like "where t.trk_lnk in (your cursor query here)". And perhaps add an order by clause as well.

If you do intend to use the cursor, consider carefully why you need to use "select top 1". Like "distinct", this usage is often a kludge to hide a logically flawed query. And the use of "select top x" without an order by clause is logically flawed since there is no guarantee which row (of many) is selected.

Comment: Thank you - temp table was the way to go :)